# ASP.NET Core empty parameters by HTTPOST from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, xmlhttprequest, http-post

I'm creating an ASP.NET Core WepApp and I have a problem to send data from javascript to my server.

HTML:

```
<button onclick="sendData()">Send Data to the Server</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
    function sendData() {

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("POST", "/Cockpit/Index", true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        xhr.send(JSON.stringify({
            "Test": "value"
        }));
     };
```

ASP.NET Core

```
namespace Paragliding.Controllers
{
    public class CockpitController : Controller
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Index(Test test)
        {
            return Json(test);
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

    }
}
```

Class Test

```
namespace Paragliding.Models
{
    public class Test
    {
        public string TestValue { set; get; }
    }
}
```

When I press the button to send the data to the server, I can see by debugging, he jump inside the method

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Index(Test test)
```

but the parameter test is always empty.

Comment: Change json parameter name from "Test" to "TestValue" inside `xhr.send`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the parameter test is always empty

You can try to modify the code as below.

```
function sendData() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            console.log(this.responseText);
        }
    };

    xhr.open("POST", "/Cockpit/Index", true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify({
        "TestValue": "blabla here"
    }));
 };
```

*Apply the `[FromBody]` attribute to parameter*

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Index([FromBody]Test test)
{
    return Json(test);
}
```

Test Result

[image]

Comment: It works, thank you very much. I have a follow question. Where exactly goes this return Json(test)? Back to the page from where I calling this method? Becuase my goal is to store this data (blabla here) in a MSSQL database. Can I put instead of "return Json(test) directly here the code for saving? Or I have to do this somewhere else? Best regards Buhli

Comment: `my goal is to store this data (blabla here) in a MSSQL database` You can do data inserting in that action method and return custom message, such as "success", "failed" etc, to indicate inserting is success or not.